# Dynamic Accordion form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to create a dynamic accordion where yo can add new accordion tabs which holds more form fields to add details for each participant of the program. My problem is I would like to make sure each time the user tries to add a new tab I would like to make sure the previous fields have been filled. My function does not work but I do not think I am going about this the best way .

Here is my code. Please leave some constructive criticism for the whole script Im sure there are some bad practices but i am here to learn . if you can help great .

Thanks
https://jsfiddle.net/gmd0gkso/#&togetherjs=HV5cxkKT14

```js
           /============================================
        //  Acordian tabs 
        //=============================================

        
   accordion_function();
   //Add new tab button
   var add_tab = document.getElementById("btn-add");
   add_tab.addEventListener ("click", add_new_tab);
   
   //Add new tab function
   function add_new_tab(){

    if(validate_form($('.accordion_holder').last()) == true){

     var clone = $('.accordion_holder').first().clone();
 
     clone.find("input:text").val("").end();
     clone.insertBefore('#button_area');
     accordion_function();
    }
    
   }

   //Add functionaly to accordian
   function accordion_function(){

    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

    for (var i=0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].onclick = function(){
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
        }
    }

    for (var i=0; i < (acc.length-1); i++){
     if($(acc[i]).hasClass('active')){
      acc[i].classList.toggle("active");
      acc[i].nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show")
     }
    }

    if(acc.length > 1){
     var last = acc[acc.length-1];
     if(!$(last).hasClass('active')){
      last.classList.toggle("active");
      last.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
     }
     
    }   
   }

   function validate_form(obj){
   
    $('obj input').each(function(){
     console.log(this);
     if(this.val()==null || this.val()==""){
      this.focus();
      this.css('border: 2px soild red');
      return false;
     }else{
      console.log("Fine");
     }
    });
    console.log("nada");
    return true;
   }
```

**HTML**

```html
<form>
<div class="accordion_holder">
 <button type="button" class="accordion">Add Student</button>
 <div class="panel">
   <p>
  <div class="row">
   <h3 class="raleway" style="margin: 20px 0;color: #fff; font-weight: 400">General INFORMATION</h3>

   <div class="form-input-lg" style="margin-right: 2%">
      <label for="fName">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"  required>
   </div>
   <div class="form-input-lg">
      <label for="lName">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="form-input-lg " style="margin-right: 2%">
      <label for="fName">Date of Birth</label>
      <input  type="date" name="fName" id="fName" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required>
   </div>
   <div class="form-input-lg">
      <label for="lName">Gender</label>
      <select name="gender" id="gender">
       <option value="male">Male</option>
       <option value="female">Female</option>
      </select>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <label for="fName" style="display:block">Dietary Requirements</label>
   <textarea rows="4" class="student-details-ta"></textarea>
  </div>
   </p>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="button_area"> 
 <button type="button" id="btn-add" style="float: right; margin: 8px ">Add <span><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></button>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="float: right; margin: 8px; font-weight: 400 ">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Code snippet isn't working. Consider creating a jsfiddle

Comment: @Daenu hey thanks for the reply I added a fiddle hope it is okay